# custom editor показать скрыть переменные

Tags: c#, unity3d, customeditor

У меня есть скрипт activator
И есть 2 состояния , кнопка и плита.

```
public class activator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("плита")]
    public GameObject plate;
    [Header("кнопка")]
    public GameObject button;

    public droper plate_Or_Button; 
    public enum droper
    {
        Button, plate,
    }
}
```

и есть у меня желание через custom editor сделать чтобы часть кода отображалась в инспекторе, в зависимости от того что я выберу в plate_Or_Button

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(activator))]
public class EditorActivator : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        
    }
}
```

но есть проблема . я нифига в этом не понимаю , и нормальной помощи в интернете не нашел .
можете помочь или показать нормальную документацию по custom editor если токовая существует.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors Буквально первая ссылка в гугл по запросу Unity custom editor

Comment: Я не понимаю что вы хотите сделать, измените свой вопрос. Конкретизируйте, что именно вам нужно сделать, приложите текущий код. Все, что я сейчас понимаю на основании вашего вопроса - это то, что вам нужно в инспекторе выводить информацию, для этого существует аттрибут `SerializeField`.

Comment: у меня есть поля для кнопки , и поля для плиты.
как мне их отображать в зависимости что я выберу 
Target.button = EditorGUILayout.IntField("button", Target.button);
нащел вот такую строчку кода. но оно не работает потому что EditorGUILayout.IntField не то что нужно

Comment: что нужно написать в место EditorGUILayout.IntField чтобы заработало 
```Target.button = EditorGUILayout.IntField("button", Target.button);```

Comment: Какой именно тип вам нужно отобразить в инспекторе? Что вам там нужно отображать, какие данные?

Comment: поле Gameobject

Comment: Как я и писал ранее, здесь подойдет `[SerializeField] private ` поле типа `GameObject`, в которое вы будете вставлять ссылку на объект, в зависимости от того, какой enum у вас выбран в `plate_Or_Button`. Не нужно все переусложнять кастомным эдитором для такой тривиальной задачи.

Answer (score 0):

спасибо всем за помощь и объяснение .
проблема решена.